# How can we restrict, that google api calls can be made only through one specific IP.

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-console

I am making a script to get google analytics data using API in php. I am able to fetch data through API, using service accounts model. Now I want to restrict that API to only return data, if API calls are made from a specific defined IP. I am unable to find any such setting in Google API console.Is there some way to achieve this goal?

Comment: You cant set a service account to only allow access from one IP,  you can with Oauth but not with service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics API can not be restricted based on user's IP address using service accounts via the mode of authentication. It can be done if it's done via oAuth2.

Comment: It can if you use Oauth2,  however not if you use service accounts .   Access to an API is controlled via the mode of authentication.  APIs don't restrict this.  Want to edit your answer please and I will upvote it